# Uniquely identifying a drive (not a partition)

Tags: linux, disk

I'm writing some automation scripts for full disk backups and I'd like to be *fairly* precise with which devices are used.

I know that one can uniquely identify a partition using UUIDs and `blkid`, but is there a way to uniquely identify a disk?

My use case is that I'm not entirely sure which order disks will be mounted on the Clonezilla distribution, and I'd like to make sure that my backups are targeting the right (whole) disk for backup.

Is there a way to find the device identifier (`/dev/sdX`) for a given disk by certain criteria?

Comment: I believe the answer to this question will vary, depending on which system you're using and the tools available there. Are you talking about a specific Linux distro, BSD, Mac OS X or something else?

Comment: Usually a Debian derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if it's in `/dev/disk/by-id/` which contains links to devices and partitions including brand and serial number.

For example `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD15EARS-00MVWB0_WD-WMAZA1856149-part1`.

If knowing the `/dev/sdX` name is important, you can get it with readlink.

```
$ readlink -f /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD15EARS-00MVWB0_WD-WMAZA1856149
/dev/sdi
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the drive serial number with `smartctl -i /dev/sdX`?

Or use the `scsi_id  --whitelisted --replace-whitespace /dev/sdX` command which is used by udev to generate the /dev/disk/by-id/ symlinks.

Be careful when you have FC multipathing as you can (should) find the same disk/LUN on multiple paths.